# llvmlite Global Variable Gets Pointerized when trying to access it with get_global

Tags: python-3.x, pointers, llvm, llvmlite

I am writing a compiler for a programming language I am making in python, I am also using llvmlite to generate ir and object files. For some reason when I use the mod.get_global function it returns the GlobalVariable but it pointerizes it. However it is a string with type i8* and it returns i8** which is making weird results when I try to print it. It also does this with ints, 64 to 64*. I don't know what is going on and I don't know how to fix it. Help would be appreciated.

Here is my shortend code with the same issue:

```
import llvmlite.ir as llvm

int_type = llvm.IntType(64)
char_type = llvm.IntType(8)
str_type = llvm.PointerType(char_type)

strid = 0
def create_str(mod, str):
    global strid
    str += "\0"
    
    typ = llvm.ArrayType(char_type, len(str))
    var = llvm.GlobalVariable(mod, typ, name=f"str.{strid}")
    var.global_constant = True
    var.unnamed_addr = True
    var.initializer = typ(bytearray(str.encode("utf8")))
    strid += 1
    
    return var.gep([int_type(0), int_type(0)])

module = llvm.Module(name="broken")

var = llvm.GlobalVariable(module, str_type, name="brokenvar")
var.global_constant = False
var.unnamed_addr = False
var.initializer = create_str(module, "Hello, World!")

# in my program you can no longer access the var variable after this point

print(module.get_global("brokenvar").type)
```

After running this program, instead of getting the expected i8*, i get i8**

Comment: If a global holds an int, then it is an int*.

Comment: Put better: a global variable is an address in memory. If that holds an int, then the address is a pointer to int, see?

Comment: Then how would I get the value out of it?

Comment: You usually [load](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoadInst.html) it.

Comment: It worked but I might also need to access it when defining another local variable. In that case, builder.load wont work.

Comment: Impressively vague problem.